# text input / textbox padding

Tags: html, css, textbox, internet-explorer-9, padding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.txtinput
{
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey" class='txtinput'><br>
</body>
</html>
```

When I keep typing text in the textbox in IE9, it goes till the end and readjusts according to the padding-right. How do I get to make it stop from going till the end, just stop before the padding.

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pMSVk/), are you trying to limit the number of characters?

Comment: @TomWalters, no. when the user start keeps typing in IE9, the characters goes till the end of the textbox irrespective of the padding, and once it reaches the end, it adjusts itself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to limit how many characters can be added into the textbox? If so then you would want to set the maxLength property.  If you are just concerned with how big you want the box to appear on screen then you would want to set the size property. Like say you wanted the box to show 50 characters with a maximum input of a 100 characters then you would just set those properties in the input tag like this:

```
First name: <input type="text" size="50" maxLength="100" name="FirstName" value="Mickey" class="txtinput">
```

If you set the maxLength smaller than the size you will have a text box that can only be filled to a certain amount (the maxLength), which I think may be what you are looking for.  Something like this:

```
First name: <input type="text" size="50" maxLength="25" name="FirstName" value="Mickey" class="txtinput">
```

Comment: no I'm not trying to set the length. when the user start keeps typing in IE9, the characters goes till the end of the textbox irrespective of the padding, and once it reaches the end, it adjusts itself.